# Sample rate Android Accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer

I saw in android documentation

*In this example, the default data delay (SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) is specified when the registerListener() method is invoked. The data delay (or sampling rate) controls the interval at which sensor events are sent to your application via the onSensorChanged() callback method. The default data delay is suitable for monitoring typical screen orientation changes and uses a delay of 200,000 microseconds. You can specify other data delays, such as SENSOR_DELAY_GAME (20,000 microsecond delay), SENSOR_DELAY_UI (60,000 microsecond delay), or SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST (0 microsecond delay). As of Android 3.0 (API Level 11) you can also specify the delay as an absolute value (in microseconds).*

What is exactly sampling rate, sometimes I saw any someone write "collect this data with 100 Hz sampling rate", It means any 100 data generated for every second?

But I am still did not understand, because when I tried this application https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fivasim.androsensor in this application we can change the setting of sampling rate (normal, game, ui, and fast). I have been tried all but the data log still same, every 1s I only get 16 data. It's true, or any something wrong in that application.

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is true.
Sampling rate is often represented as "Hz" meaning how many times the sensor read raw-sensor-data(i.e., x, y, z) per seconds.

I don't know what the Android Application you used, But
Documentation related sensors (e.g., SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, registerListener)
sometime don't appropriately reflect real-sensor's characteristics depending on devices (including smart-watches of Android Wear)

One of the reasons might be the vendor of sensor is different depending on devices. Also, the software-module might not be well implemented as the Documentations in Android Developer sites.

The best way to understand the how the sensor works in a certain device is 
to confirm how it works with the device in person.